# mplayerctrl process screen issue

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

When I try to run the app via double clicking the ".py" file the python console screen pops up as usual. To prevent it I change the extension to ".pyw" but then mplayer.exe console screen pops up. how can I hide that screen.

Here is the screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXBLk.png

Comment: Hungry for code. Show yummy code (its probably the way you are calling it in your script)

Comment: We need more info. Are you using the 3rd party mplayer control for wxPython? If not, how are you calling mplayer? Is this really  wxPython question?

Comment: dav1d the creator of mplayerctrl has fixed the bug. problem solved. https://bitbucket.org/dav1d/mplayerctrl/changeset/c680a1d99ad2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue no longer exists with the fix below https://bitbucket.org/dav1d/mplayerctrl/commits/c680a1d99ad2/